# How do I hide a div with jQuery and keep it hidden using a cookie?

Tags: jquery, cookies, jquery-cookie

I'm trying to hide a div named #video-toggle, and have that div remain hidden on subsequent page loads using a cookie. I'm a complete jQuery newbie and I have no idea what I've been doing wrong.

All that happens when I click on the designated link is the alert pops up informing me that the cookie is currently null. No value is being set. Anyone able to lead me in the right direction?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 

        jQuery('a#slick-slidetoggle').click(function() { 
            $.cookie('isHidden','true', { path: '/' });
            alert( $.cookie('isHidden') );
            return false;
        }); 

        var hidden = $.cookie('isHidden');

        if (hidden == null) {
            jQuery('#video-toggle').show();
        }

    });
```

Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 0):

you need this jquery plugin:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie

Check this site too: [link](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/)

Comment: I'm using the plugin though. Surely there must be a problem with my code.

Comment: Maybe you have problem with cookie path!

Comment: Try $.cookie('isHidden','true');

Answer (score 0):

Maybe when setting your cookie try:

```
$.cookie("isHidden","true");
```

If that works then there is a problem with passing the path option.

Let me know how you get on.